# Get all nested keys and values using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq, key-value

I have a json like this

```json
{
  "outer1": {
    "outer2": {
      "outer3": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
      }
    },
    "outer4": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    }
  }
}
```

I want output to be

```
[outer1.outer2.outer3]
key1 = value1
key2 = value2

[outer1.outer2.outer4]
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
```

I tried `jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)")|.[]' test.json` But its not what is what I want exactly

Comment: Please post valid JSON: make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: How "dynamic" is your JSON? Are the intermediate and root keys fixed or variable?

Comment: nothing is fixed :(

Comment: You want `[outer1.outer2.outer4]` even though `"outer4"` is not in the `"outer2"` object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your input looks like this:

```json
{
  "outer1": {
    "outer2": {
      "outer3": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
      },
      "outer4": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could use the `--stream` option to read the input as a stream of path-value pairs. For instance:

```bash
jq --stream -n '
  reduce (inputs | select(has(1))) as [$path, $val] ({};
    .[$path[:-1] | join(".")][$path[-1]] = $val
  )
'
```

```json
{
  "outer1.outer2.outer3": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  },
  "outer1.outer2.outer4": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
}
```

Next, format this JSON according to your needs. For example using `to_entries` for both levels:

```bash
jq --stream -nr '
  reduce (inputs | select(has(1))) as [$path, $val] ({};
    .[$path[:-1] | join(".")][$path[-1]] = $val
  )
  | to_entries[] | "[\(.key)]", (
      .value | to_entries[] | "\(.key) = \(.value)"
    ), ""
'
```

```
[outer1.outer2.outer3]
key1 = value1
key2 = value2

[outer1.outer2.outer4]
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
```

---

Alternatively, combine both steps into a single `foreach` iteration with a sliding context window as state:

```bash
jq --stream -nr '
  foreach (inputs | select(has(1))) as [$path, $val] ([];
    [last, ($path[:-1] | join("."))];
    (select(first != last) | "\n[\(last)]"), "\($path[-1]) = \($val)"
  )                                                              
'
```

Comment: How do I supply a json input file to this?
And thanks :)

Comment: Just append it to the command: `jq --stream -nr '…' file.json`

Comment: this is awesome - seriously

Answer (score 2):

My take is this:

```
. as $data
| [ path(.. | scalars) ]
| map( . as $p | { prefix: $p[0:-1]|join("."), key: $p[-1], value: $data | getpath($p) })
| group_by(.prefix)[]
| "[\(first.prefix)]", (.[] | "\(.key)=\(.value)")
```

Basically:

- find all scalars,
- get the paths to these scalars (like `["outer1","outer2","outer3","key1"]`)
- create intermediate representation of the path splitted into a prefix like `outer1.outer2.outer3`), a key (`key1`) and the actual value (`value1`)
- group these using the prefix
- format

Comment: You could contract `path(.. | scalars)` to `paths(scalars)`, and then `[path…] | map(. as $p | {…})` to `[path… | . as $p | {…}]`.

Comment: You could also append `, ""` at the very end to produce an empty line between groups.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to generate a TOML-encoded document, also consider employing [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), which is a `jq` wrapper for processing (YAML, XML, and) TOML documents. The TOML processor is called `tomlq`, and it transcodes between TOML and JSON, so that `jq` filters can be applied directly. For your use-case, though, the filter only needs to emit the contents of a variable which is populated with the contents of your JSON input file using jq's `--argfile` option (because reading from `stdin` and direct file arguments are expected to be TOML-encoded, thus the use of `-n`). Eventually, the `-t` option converts the (final) JSON document (back) to TOML. The output slightly differs from your desired output, but if your goal is to produce a TOML document, you could benefit from `tomlq` automatically providing for a valid and well-formed structure.

```bash
tomlq -n -t '$f' --argfile f file.json
```

```ini
[outer1.outer2]
[outer1.outer2.outer3]
key1 = "value1"
key2 = "value2"

[outer1.outer2.outer4]
key1 = "value1"
key2 = "value2"
```